# Does the delphi TBitmap support an alpha channel

Tags: delphi, alpha, bmp

I'm hearing people say that it is not.

However, I created a TBitmap and cleared the entire area by

```
For I := 1 to bmp.Width do
  For J := 0 to bmp.Height do
    bmp.canvas.Pixels[I,J]:= $00000000;
```

Then I drew anti-aliased text onto the bitmap and saved it to file. Upon opening it in gimp it shows the transparency information.

Does anyone have a definitive answer on this and if it does work then more information on how it works? I've tried playing around with the last byte and I'm not getting the expected results when i open it in gimp.

Comment: Using `Pixels[]` can be very slow.  Investigate using ScanLine instead - you need to know the pixel format to know how many bytes per pixel, but if you're using pf32bit that's easy (4 bytes.)  See http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Scanline.htm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does, but you have to set

```
bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
```

Comment: +1 Great :) With which VCL version is this supported?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this was already in D7. Probably earlier, too.

Answer (score 3):

The Delphi TBitmap is just a wrapper around the Windows BITMAP object. So, yes it does support alpha channels, but clearly you must set the PixelFormat property appropriately.