# Delphi, Direct2D, TBitmap and Transparency

Tags: delphi, transparent, direct2d, wic

I'm struggling to be able to draw a `TBitmap` with transparency onto a `TDirect2DCanvas` without losing the transparency.

Having created a `TBitmap` which acts as the back-buffer for my drawing operation as follows:

```
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
bmp.Canvas.Brush.Handle := 0;
bmp.SetSize(100, 100);
bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
bmp.Transparent := true;
bmp.TransparentColor := clRed;
bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
bmp.Canvas.Ellipse(bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
```

I then need to draw it onto my `TDirect2DCanvas`, however the following draws the `TBitmap` but removes all transparency - the background colour is drawn as red whereas if I just draw onto the `TForm.Canvas` then the background is transparent.

```
// Drawing onto the TDirect2DCanvas results in a red background
AEventArgs.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp);

// Drawing onto the TForm.Canvas gives the correct result
Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp);
```

My understanding now leads me on to `ID2D1Bitmap` and `IWICBitmap` interfaces, so, I can attempt to create an `ID2D1Bitmap` from the `TBitmap` using the following code (and *assuming* that the pixel format is copied across):

```
var
    bmp : TBitmap;
    temp : ID2D1Bitmap;
begin
    // Code to initialize the TBitmap goes here (from above)

    // Create an ID2D1Bitmap from a TBitmap
    temp := AEventArgs.Canvas.CreateBitmap(bmp);

    // Draw the ID2D1Bitmap onto the TDirect2DCanvas
    AEventArgs.Canvas.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(temp);
```

Now that I have an `ID2D1Bitmap`, the result is still the same - a red background with no transparency. I guess its entirely feasible that the Direct2D side of things uses a different method for transparency but looking at the propertys of the `ID2D1Bitmap` provides no clues.

My next guess is to go down the `IWICBitmap` interface.

Ultimately, my question is: is there a more straightforward or obvious thing that I've missed from the above which would allow the transparent `TBitmap` to be drawn onto the `TDirect2DCanvas` surface? Or is all this pain necessary in order to maintain the transparency?

**Update**

Ok, so after doing a bit more digging around, I can now convert the `TBitmap` to an `IWICBitmap` and then onto an `ID2D1Bitmap` however the issue still remains - transparency which is present in the `TBitmap` is not copied through when rendering to the `TDirect2DCanvas`.

```
// Create the IWICBitmap from the TBitmap
GetWICFactory.CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(bmp.Handle, bmp.Palette, WICBitmapUsePremultipliedAlpha, wic);
wic.GetPixelFormat(pif);

// The PixelFormat is correct as `GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA` which is
// B8G8R8A8_UNORM and PREMULTIPLIED

// Create the IWICFormatConverter
GetWICFactory.CreateFormatConverter(fc);
fc.Initialize(wic, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, nil, 0.0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

// Now, create the ID2D1Bitmap
AEventArgs.Canvas.RenderTarget.CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(fc, nil, temp);
temp.GetPixelFormat(fmt);

// Here, PixelFormat is correct matching the PixelFormat from the IWICBitmap

// Draw the bitmap to the Canvas
AEventArgs.Canvas.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(temp);
```

And the result is still a non-transparent bitmap.

So the final thing I've looked into is the PixelFormat of the ID2D1RenderTarget which is the underlying render target of the TDirect2DCanvas.

```
// Create the canvas
fCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Self.Handle);
fCanvas.RenderTarget.GetPixelFormat(pf); 

// This gives me a PixelFormat of
// B8G8R8A8_UNORM but D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE
```

So I'm guessing that the real issue is to do with the fact that the `ID2D1RenderTarget` PixelFormat is ignoring the alpha.

Comment: > *"..  transparency which is present in the TBitmap .."* > That's what you've got wrong all along. That bitmap has no transparency. It's the VCL that draws it *transparently* with the information you supply through properties of the TBitmap (see `TransparentStretchBlt` in 'graphics').

Answer (score 2):

The real issue is not in the methods you are calling but the shear fact that in VCL application by default TBitmap uses 24bit RGB pixel format which does not have an alpha channel needed for alpha transparency.

If you want to use alpha transparency with TBitmap you first need to set its pixel format to `pf32bit`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680460/3636228

Also don't forget to set Alpha channel to 0 for every pixel that you want it to be transparent.

You see Direct2D does not support same transparency as it is used in VCL where you can simply set the transparent color and every pixel of that specific color is simply ignored.

Comment: @SilverWarrior thanks for your comments. Any pointers as to how I can go between the VCL TBitmap and Direct2D while maintaining transparency? I've had a look at using a GDI compatible render target but this still doesn't work even though the alpha is set up correctly on both the TBitmap and the render target - it still gets ignored. There doesn't appear to be much helpful information around. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try and use FMX.Graphics.TBitmap instead of regular VCL TBitmap as I have suggested in a different question for different purposes that you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38551815/3636228 Note that I have never tried this or seeny anboddy else do it but based on the fact that FireMonkey is using DirectX for rendering on Windows it might actually work. I'll do some testing when I come home.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source of TDirect2DCanvas.CreateBitmap, you'll see:

```
  ...
  if (Bitmap.PixelFormat <> pf32bit) or (Bitmap.AlphaFormat = afIgnored) then
    BitmapProperties.pixelFormat.alphaMode := D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE
  else
    BitmapProperties.pixelFormat.alphaMode := D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
```

So to make it work, you have to match the conditions:

```
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    bmp.AlphaFormat := TAlphaFormat.afPremultiplied;
```

Then you have to prepare the alpha channel of every pixel. In your case, red is transparent, so you should do something like this:

```
for y := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do begin
  Line := bmp.Scanline[y];
  for x := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do begin
    if (line[x].r =255) and (line[x].g = 0) and (line[x].b = 0) then
    Line[x].A := 0
  else
    Line[x].A := 255;
end;
```

Then it comes:

```
temp := AEventArgs.Canvas.CreateBitmap(BMP);
AEventArgs.Canvas.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(temp);
```

Took me entire weekend to figure it out myself, hope it helps you or someone else.